# Joomla login page url as a user, not as a administrator

Tags: joomla

I have a user name and password to access Joomla website as a user not as a administrator. As a administrator I know it is e.g.

```
         www.example.com/administrator
```

but what is the URL to login for other user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to login to joomla administrator and publish the login module:

```
Extensions -> Module Manager -> New -> Login
```

You could also create a login item in your menu:

```
Menus -> Your Menu -> New -> Menu Item Type -> Users Manager -> Login Form
```

If you don't want to have your login visible in the site you could add after your domain:

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=login
```

Hope this helps